# Python 2.7 : dict(zip()) is not working for boolean values

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my program.

```
l1 = ['alpha','image']
l2 = ['False','False']

d = dict(zip(l1,l2))

if d['image']:
   print("passing")
```

Result:
passing
here d['image'] is False. But still the its going inside the if condition. Why is it going inside the loop even if the value is False?

Comment: The string "False" resolves to True. `if 'False': print(True)` -> prints True. `if False: print(True)` -> prints nothing.

Comment: Instead do this `d = dict(zip(l1, map(bool, l2)))`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `string 'False'` not a Boolean object.

```
l1 = ['alpha','image']
l2 = [False,False]      #--->Boolean

d = dict(zip(l1,l2))

if d['image']:
   print("passing")
```

**Edit as per comment**

```
if d['image'] == "True":
   print("passing")
```

Comment: Thank you . I am reading the values from csv file using csv.reader. In that case, even if the value is False, csv.reader is reading it as 'False'. How can i resolve this? i need to read 2 rows from csv file and zip it

Comment: Updated snippet.  Use string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The value is a *string* still. so you're just evaluating whether the string is empty or not.

If you really need booleans, remove the quotes or check if the string is "True"

```
'False' == 'True'
```

Comment: Thank you . I am reading the values from csv file using csv.reader. In that case, even if the value is False, csv.reader is reading it as 'False'. How can i resolve this? i need to read 2 rows from csv file and zip it

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the comments that `'False'` is read from a file and thus must be a string, then you must compare it to the string `'False'`. Although, I suggest making this check case insensitive.

```
l1 = ['alpha','image']
l2 = ['False','False']

d = dict(zip(l1,l2))

if d['image'].lower() == 'false':
   print("passing")
```

A more general way to convert a string to its boolean equivalent would be the following.

```
def string_to_bool(s):
    if s.lower() == 'true':
        return True

    elif s.lower() == 'false':
        return False

    else:
        raise ValueError('string has no boolean conversion')
```

You could then do

```
if not string_to_bool(d['image']):
   print("passing")
```